# how to use setContentView in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android development, i want to use setContentView to change between two layouts, i have made two activities and two layouts, the first button "b1" successfully switches to second layout but the second button "b2" doesn't do anything
Here is the code :

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>   Button b1;
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>       b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
>       b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>           @Override
>           public void onClick(View v) {
>
>               setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
>           }});}}
> ```

// --

> ```
> public class second extends Activity{
>   Button b2;
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
>   {
>       super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
>       b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
>       b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>           @Override
>           public void onClick(View v) {
>               finish();
>           }});}}
> ```

//--

> ```
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/b1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
>         android:text="Button" />
> ```

//--

> ```
> <Button
>         android:id="@+id/b2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Button" />
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are just changing layout. Not transfering control to second activity. Try this-

MainActivity-

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Button b1;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, second.class)); 
          finish();
          }
       });
     }}
```

second-

```
public class second extends Activity{
  Button b2;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
      b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
      b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              finish();
          }
       });
     }}
```

Dont forget to add second activity in manifest like this-

```
<activity android:name=".second"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just change your layout in same activity.
If you want to jump to others activity you need to use `Intent`

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
              startActivity(it);
          }});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to switch between activities use intent not switching b/w layouts.
 replace

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
```

with below code and try

```
    Intent  intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), second .class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i used Intent, but the problem is that the layouts "pops", unlike the setContentView(), the screen just switches without noticing, so if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to switch over into second activity means you have to use the intente function...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActicity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

*You have two layouts* -

**1)** R.layout.activity_main

**2)** R.layout.activity_second

You are doing right to switch to second activity by calling -

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
```

So it is working on a button click.

Then to call the previous layout back call -

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Here is the code -

```
public class second extends Activity{
  Button b2;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
      b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
      b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          }});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to change layouts in **the same activity** - you should use `Fragments`.

Now, you are changing between two layouts in the same Activity. If you declared first Button in your first layout, and second button in the second layout - your second button will not work (as you see) seeing there is no corresponding code in the first Activity.

If you want to switch between to Avtivities (and not just the layouts you need to use `Intents`.

To sum things up:

If you want to use two or more layouts using one activity - use `Fragments`.

If you want to use two different Activities - use `Intents`